# SQL remove duplicated rows with names alike

Tags: sql

My table contains entries with name like this:

```
12345
A12345
234567
A234567
A99999
```

I'd like to remove the rows that has Axxxxx where the xxxxx are existing in the table. So in my example I'd like to leave with:

```
12345
234567
A99999
```

but remove the A12345 and A234567 since 12345 and 234567 are in the table...

Comment: Hey James, remember if your question has been answered, then you should select an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I thought of:

```
delete from Data2 where id in (
    select d.id from Data d
    left join Data1 d1 on (d.id = CONCAT('A', d1.id))
    where d1.id is not null
)
```

You can play with it [here](http://sqlize.com/1VS018MN8l)

This is a query with a substring... but I think it is a little less efficient (you can tell us later):

```
delete from Data where id in (
    select d2.id from Data1 d1
    join Data2 d2 on (d1.id = substring(d2.id, 2))
);
```

Note mysql substring considers the first character to be numbered as 1 not 0.

You can play with it [here](http://sqlize.com/hvU7o5CAeT)

Answer (score 1):

```
delete 
  from #mytable 
 where exists ( select 'x' 
                  from #mytable b
                 where #mytable.col = 'A' + b.col );
```

Answer (score 0):

This will delete all rows with Axxxxx where there is a row for xxxxx:

```
delete from mytable
where name in (
    select CONCAT('A', name)
    from mytable
    where name not like 'A%')
)
```

#### Edited:

I have the logic reversed in the previous version

Comment: This looks like you are deleting `12345` instead of `A12345`.

Comment: @Guvante Thx. I misread the question. I have swapped the logic in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from mytable 
where name in (select b.name
  from mytable a
  INNER JOIN mytable b
    on a.name = SubString(b.name, 1, LEN(b.name))
  WHERE Substring(a.name, 0, 1) <> 'A' AND Substring(b.name, 0, 1) = 'A'
    )
```

try this. u might have to twick substring. but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE 
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE name IN (
                SELECT name
                  FROM MyTable AS T1
                INTERSECT
                SELECT 'A' + name
                  FROM MyTable AS T1
               );
```